# Assign titles to a column according to percentiles in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to solve Python problems into SQL code.

I would like to assign titles according to the grade in a new column.

For example:

- A for the top 0.9% of the column
- B for next 15% of the column
- C for  next 25% of the column
- D for next 30% of the column
- E for next 13% of  the column
- F for rest of the column

There is this column:

```
Grades
2.3
3
2
3.3
3.5
3.6
3.2
2.1
2.3
3.7
3.3
3.1
4.4
4.3
1.4
4.5
3.5
```

I don't know how sqlite can work  with this since it doesn't have a function like `quantile` that languages like R have.

Something that tried but not even close is this :

```
SELECT x
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY x
LIMIT 1
OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable) / 2
```

to get at half of the column.

Comment: This problem is just not well-suited for SQLite.  You should consider a more powerful database.

Comment: What does the desired result look like? Keep in mind that all columns will have to have the same number of rows.